# Should ReactJS server side rerender each route

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I`m little bit confused about SSR rendering logic.

I have made some ReactJS SSR applications, looked multiple videos and texts to practice and I`m not sure how it should work.

I know that SSR is good for rendering speed, SEO, etc, but should SSR need to render only first time if client opens page and then send it to client side to take over or should it rerender each time (takes a lot of time and uses unnecessary network traffic)

Example - foo.com loads first time, client clicks some link that routes to another url - foo.com/info

Should this process use < Link/> and not rerender page, or?

Because rerendering page is not necessary for client but is necessary for crawler bots.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSR rendering is only needed for first load.
First you load page from server using SSR and after that you load new pages using client side requests.